# Dynamically generate object from another object with value mapping

Tags: typescript

Using TypeScript, I am trying to dynamically generate an object that has the same keys as the object it's being generated upon. The values of those keys, however, must be objects that have method called exampleMethod that returns the value of the key from the original object.

I came up with this:

```js
const obj = { a: "valueA", b: "valueB" } as const;
const objKeys = Object.keys(obj) as (keyof typeof obj)[];

const example = objKeys.reduce(
  (acc, v) => {
    acc[v] = {
      exampleMethod() {
        return obj[v];
      },
    };
    return acc;
  },
  {} as {
    -readonly [K in keyof typeof obj]: { exampleMethod(): (typeof obj)[K] };
  },
);
```

But I get an error on implementation of exampleMethod saying:

```
Type '() => "valueA" | "valueB"' is not assignable to type '(() => "valueA") & (() => "valueB")'.
  Type '() => "valueA" | "valueB"' is not assignable to type '() => "valueA"'.
    Type '"valueA" | "valueB"' is not assignable to type '"valueA"'.
      Type '"valueB"' is not assignable to type '"valueA"'.
```

I think it has to do with type of argument v being "a" | "b".

The resulting object needs to be as follows:

```js
const example = {
  a: {
    exampleMethod() {
      return "a";
    },
  },
  b: {
    exampleMethod() {
      return "b";
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: This is an issue with lack of support for *correlated unions* as described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  The easiest thing to do is use a type assertion and move on, if you're sure it's safe.  Otherwise you can refactor to use generics as per [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) and get a little more compiler-verified safety, but it might not be worth it to you.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w1agGw). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz brilliant! I think I'm gonna roll with generics. Also, do you think it is possible to ditch the type annotation for the resulting object? Maybe, there is another helper besides `reduce`, that just gets the job done? All I really care about is the structure of base (`obj`) and resulting (`example`) objects.

Comment: ... and the type inferation, of course

Comment: I'll write up an answer.  But your followup questions are probably out of scope... the type annotations are what make it work, and I'd need to start thinking about reimplementing your code and various typings for it.  Certainly there are ways other than `reduce`, you can just `forEach` it (given that you're really just using `reduce` to modify an existing object), but I'm not inclined to explore that here. If you have more questions you can't answer, you should probably post them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this code

```
const obj = { a: "valueA", b: "valueB" } as const;
type Obj = typeof obj;
type Example = {
  -readonly [P in keyof Obj]: { exampleMethod(): Obj[P] };
};
const objKeys = Object.keys(obj) as (keyof Obj)[];
const example = objKeys.reduce(
  (acc, k) => {
    acc[k] = { exampleMethod() { return obj[k] } }; // error!
    // ------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // Type '() => "valueA" | "valueB"' is not assignable to
    // type '(() => "valueA") & (() => "valueB")'.
    return acc;
  }, {} as Example
);
```

the type checker is unable to see the *correlation* between the type `acc[k]` of the property being written and the type `obj[k]` of the return value of the method you're assigning to it.  The problem is that the key `k` is of a [*union* type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `"a" | "b"`, and when you index with it, the compiler is only looking at its *type* and not its *identity*.  Imagine you had `acc[k1] = { exampleMethod() { return obj[k2] } }` where `k1` and `k2` were both of type `"a" | "b"`.  Clearly that would not be safe, right?  And the type checker can't tell the difference between that and the version you're using. It doesn't analyze the code multiple times and say "if `k` is `"a"` then it's fine, and if `k` is `"b"` then it's fine, so it's fine either way".  It just looks at it once and fails to see the correlation.

This lack of support for correlated union types is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

---

The easiest way to proceed is just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that your code is correct, possibly like this:

```
const example = objKeys.reduce(
  (acc, k) => {
    acc[k] = { exampleMethod() { return obj[k] as any } }; 
    // assert -------------------------------> ^^^^^^        
    return acc;
  }, {} as Example
);
```

This is just saying "I know what I'm doing, leave me alone" to the type checker. It stops trying (and failing) to verify type safety and just lets you move on.  Of course that means you have to be careful, since it will let you do something unsafe just as easily as it will let you do something safe.  But if you're sure the code is right, this is an easy fix.  And since you're already using type assertions on `Object.keys()` and the accumulator object to `reduce()`, it's not like one more assertion will make much difference in that respect.

---

Still, if you want to keep some of that compiler-verified type safety, you'll need to refactor so the compiler follows your logic.  The recommended approach to deal with correlated unions is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), and involves replacing unions with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  You need to express the operations in terms of a basic key-value type (like `Obj`, which is already there) and generic [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into that type or into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that type.

Like this:

```
type Example<K extends keyof Obj = keyof Obj> = {
  -readonly [P in K]: { exampleMethod(): Obj[P] };
};
const example = objKeys.reduce(
  <K extends "a" | "b">(acc: Example<K>, k: K) => {
    acc[k] = { exampleMethod() { return obj[k] } } // okay
    return acc;
  },
  {} as Example
);
```

Here I've redefined `Example` to make it generic in `K`, a particular key of `Obj`.  Note that `K` [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `keyof Obj`, so when you just write `Example` you get the same type as before.  But now `Example<"a">` is equivalent to `Pick<Example, "a">`, a supertype of `Example`.

The callback to `reduce()` is now generic in `K extends keyof Obj`, so `k` is of generic type `K` (instead of `keyof Obj`) and `acc` is now of type `Example<K>` (instead of `Example`).  Now the type checker is happy with `acc[k] = { exampleMethod() { return obj[k] } }` because `acc[k]` is of type `Example<K>[K]`, a generic type that can be seen as `{ exampleMethod(): Obj[K] }`, which is the type of the assigned object.  And the only reason the type checker sees that is because `Example<K>` is written explicitly as a mapped type over `Obj`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPkkqJLAsgAoBOA9gEYYRh6HHHy3BQAuSDAKyQBePEhAAuJACIAbpgCuEAILSANEnpS5iiACFpSAL7ioSTtx4BuIux4BPGMgDy9IaIdPaAM35ub7EieyACiAB7gMEwirIHEALTUECAAJlwY9kgA2pRIAJbASADWEPY+SK4CALpSuEgQEWBREACyEDwAFrQpABQAlFKVOVXGAexGYxxcvH4CANKlZqKVEPA8AHQl9lA9gn2mSD1b5ZV9WVWT5tN8DZHRooIL2+tJKQqIPbaBPQjwGkX7YQAPlicWIvyyRRGojqtyaTDanW6-TESR4CmohUEkJGJgmSAA9AT6tQ6NQAIRfOJEpDxOn0kEAP2ZLNZLKpgRpABVHMgAOQo4EyeQYJSqJAAH2FugMfPyZmAtD4ICgUDyAHNQIxkDxaBz2DTgkgBYKQTpRSppPsAGSHU3Si0GPp89b64hojGFX6XYhGDS4EwqpDhO4QKl9Gy2IxsEjgaBwRCoBS8ACqUAgPKcylVEGoPDyXFYVIsM0EMTqkgdYvUmm0IqUBmMBxL1ipRsqMWC5UElyNIfhyBh+sSyTSwAy2VyBWKpRObhqYjhzURXV6AwqbmGoypE2L11mTyWG4Eqw2Wx2ewOR1nvlO50uLfqjWaMUeixeEDeH31P3gf2KgIggQYLgn+OLlk+oYrsi+x1B6mKzOBQYgMAmR4lYSBuoSxIqumea0vShFEcRJFESCAB6lFUSBmE0fBXp-j6xj+oGZj9s04ZjNGtikPGFBIAA4hAwC5nk8BmMB7CPmWMLiHWuiqBoWhVvohisVcli9ryx6dry3b+HulgHosMQrGsmyLLsbj7EG15lLe1n3m22nsUwAA8cxPjwwkpGYxwOe4M72ceIJDmCI6pOkmQ5PkhRzAusLPgi7Srv0gybpQuKXLugSPku9zGc8rzvBAnxgh5Xk+WY0ggIYUrSPQ0hAr+8BSK5EAeUC-xSHMgGgmCEJQhB+WtClMGou0nqIUNeJYfR4iMfqfr6gGBztZxUb4EYQA)